# Swift Tableview moves up when altering table width

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a view that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7OGq.jpg), where I have a tableview next to an scrollview.

The tableview has a fixed tablecell height, no sections and vertical scrolling. (just a standard tableview)

The scrollview can scroll horizontal, and by doing so that tableview width decreases or increases. (and the scrollview does the opposite)

So far everything works.

The problem is that when scrolling the scrollview (and hence increasing or decreasing the tableview width) the tableview just scrolls up slightly.

My first thought was that the tableviewoffset.y would just change, but apparently the offset.y does not change at all.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

edit:
I understand that my problem is not quite clear yet. 
I constructed a example project to illustrate it. ([Download link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ks38u62p0j5gnjj/example.zip?dl=0))

Follow the following steps.

1. Run the project
2. scroll the tableview (left side) all the way down (it has number 49)
3. drag "test" to the left or right
4. Look back at the tableview and you can notice that the tableview "scrolled" up.

(step 2b scroll to any table cell number (except 1) and the problems also occurs; number 49 is just the example)

edit 2:
Problem has been solved...

Inserting the following lines solved the problem.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
        return 55
}
```

Thanks anyways!

(my code of the viewcontroller)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollViewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var TableViewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var defaultTableViewWidth:CGFloat!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.defaultTableViewWidth = self.TableViewWidth.constant
        self.scrollViewWidth.constant = 350
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 55
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TabCell", for: indexPath) as! TabCell
        cell.clientLabel.text = "E"
        cell.debtNumberLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        print("b - offset: \(self.TableView.contentOffset.y)")
        print("b - rowheight: \(self.TableView.rowHeight)")
        print("b - cont height: \(self.TableView.contentSize.height)")

        if scrollView == ScrollView
        {
            if scrollView.contentOffset.x < 0
            {
                self.TableViewWidth.constant += abs(scrollView.contentOffset.x)
            }
            else if scrollView.contentOffset.x > 0 && self.TableViewWidth.constant >= 60
            {
                self.TableViewWidth.constant = max(self.TableViewWidth.constant - scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0.0)

                if self.TableViewWidth.constant >= 60
                {
                    scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
                }
                else
                {
                    self.TableViewWidth.constant = 60
                }
            }
        }

        print("a - offset: \(self.TableView.contentOffset.y)")
        print("a - rowheight: \(self.TableView.rowHeight)")
        print("a - cont height: \(self.TableView.contentSize.height)")
        print(" ")

    }

    func animateHeader(height: CGFloat)
    {
        self.TableViewWidth.constant = height
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)
    {
        if self.TableViewWidth.constant > self.defaultTableViewWidth
        {
            animateHeader(height: self.defaultTableViewWidth)
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        if self.TableViewWidth.constant > self.defaultTableViewWidth
        {
            animateHeader(height: self.defaultTableViewWidth)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Even with your [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7OGq.jpg), I'm not exactly sure what you are expecting, and what is moving in the wrong direction. Could you be a little clearer. You can edit your post with the edit button, or make your image clearer by adding annotations and direction arrows to it.

Answer (score 0):

the following information would help debug

- What constraints are you using?
- Is the tableview frame position fixed or does it change when you drag? Maybe a video of what's happening would help debug this.

(I cannot comment yet which is why I am posting this as an answer)